# Legacy Bootstrap Styling Issue with Select2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am using a legacy version of bootstrap (2.3.2) along side a plugin called Select2 which creates some fancy dropdowns. I am running into an issue when using it with Input Group Addons.

When trying to put an addon in front of the select that has been turned into the select2 dropdown, it is messing with the alignment/placement of the field.

It's very basic form code so I have to assume its the CSS of either bootstrap or select2 that's causing the issue:

Any thoughts on what CSS could be causing this problem? Input Group addons and forms are native so I'd say select2 is adding some CSS that has a padding or margin that's causing this.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="submitRequest" id="submitRequest" method="post" action="requestContentv2.php">
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><small>Request Type</small>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend"> <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i></span>

            <select class="span5" id="e1">
                <option></option>
                <option value="Create New">Create New</option>
                <option value="Delete/Remove">Delete/Remove</option>
            </select>
        </div> <span class="help-block"><small>Select a request type from the list above.</small></span>

    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Here is a fiddle of the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bs6b4fu7/1/

Comment: If you have the ability to upgrade Select2 at all, I might as well warn you that you are using a version of Select2 (3.2) that is incredibly old and seriously lacking in areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n8xdgcer/) what you are looking for?

```
.select2-container {
  margin:0;
}
.add-on{
    float:left;
}
```

Note - Do you want it to not collapse on smaller sizes?

Update - You will want to use this media query to override bootstrap's legacy media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.span5 {
    width: 380px;
}
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work fine; I appreciate it. I want it to remain the same size field regardless of how short the option label is which seems to happen just find with the span5.

Answer (score 1):

How about removing the "span5" class? That worked for me...

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="submitRequest" id="submitRequest" method="post" action="requestContentv2.php">
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><small>Request Type</small>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend"> <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i></span>

            <select id="e1">
                <option></option>
                <option value="Create New">Create New</option>
                <option value="Delete/Remove">Delete/Remove</option>
            </select>
        </div> <span class="help-block"><small>Select a request type from the list above.</small></span>

    </div>
</div>
```

For the purpose of the Fiddle, I've also removed the first `<option>` tag
https://jsfiddle.net/bs6b4fu7/3/

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bs6b4fu7/6/):

**> small:**
[image]

**responsive:**

[image]

```
.input-prepend .select2-container .select2-choice {
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:20px;
    height:20px;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
}
.input-prepend {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}
.add-on {
    float: left;
}
[class*="span"].select2-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    float: none;
    min-width: 320px;

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        /* responsive styles */
    }
}
```